# Using RemoveLayer in arcpy.mapping?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am trying to use RemoveLayer within the mapping module, but seem to be getting mixed results. I do the following to add a layer to the map

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") # define map document
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\test.lyr") # define layer object
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd) # list data frames
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df[0],lyr) #  add layer
```

Now that the layer is added, I am trying to use `arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer` to remove the layer from the map. I do the following.

```
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df[0],lyr)
```

But this doesn't work. The layers still exist in the map. But if I try the following code where I list the layers and then loop through and use RemoveLayer, it works now. Why?

```
lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for i in lyrlist:
    arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df[0],i)
```

Is this because Layer objects don't work with RemoveLayer for some reason?

Comment: you will probably need to get your layer from the data frame (ListLayers) and not just create a new one.. even though the datasource and name of the layer is the same a newly created layer is *different* to an existing layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still referencing the layer file with your variable `lyr`. You'll need to find it in your mxd before you can remove it.

Maybe something like this:

```
lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
lyr = [l for l in lyrlist if l.name == "test"] [0]
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df[0],lyr)
```